# Tensorflow AssertionError "gradients list should have been aggregated by now"

Tags: tensorflow

I have a function `f` that is internally using some `tf.while_loop`s and `tf.gradients` to compute the value `y = f(x)`. Something like this

```
def f( x ):
   ... 
   def body( g, x ):
        # Compute the gradient here 
        grad = tf.gradients( g, x )[0]
        ... 
        return ... 
   return tf.while_loop( cond, body, parallel_iterations=1 )
```

There are a few hundred lines of code. But I believe that those are the important points...

Now when I evaluate `f(x)`, I get exactly the value I expect ..

```
y = known output of f(x)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    fx = f(x)
    print("Error = ", y - sess.run(fx, feed_dict)) # Prints 0
```

However, when I try to evaluate the gradient of `f(x)` with respect to `x`, that is,

```
grads = tf.gradients( fx, x )[0]
```

I get the error

```
AssertionError: gradients list should have been aggregated by now.
```

Here is the full trace:

```
  File "C:/Dropbox/bob/tester.py", line 174, in <module>
    grads = tf.gradients(y, x)[0]
  File "C:\Anaconda36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gradients_impl.py", line 649, in gradients
    return [_GetGrad(grads, x) for x in xs]
  File "C:\Anaconda36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gradients_impl.py", line 649, in <listcomp>
    return [_GetGrad(grads, x) for x in xs]
  File "C:\Anaconda36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gradients_impl.py", line 727, in _GetGrad
    "gradients list should have been aggregated by now.")
AssertionError: gradients list should have been aggregated by now.
```

Could somebody please outline likely causes for this error? I have no idea where to even start looking for the issue...

Some observations:

1. Note that I have set the parallel iterations for the while loop to 1. This 
   should mean that there is no errors due to reading and writing from multiple threads.
2. If I discard the while loop, and just have `f` return `body()`, then the code runs:

   ```
   # The following does not crash, but we removed the while_loop, so the output is incorrect
   def f( x ):
      ... 
      def body( g, x ):
           # Compute the gradient here 
           grad = tf.gradients( g, x )[0]
           ... 
           return ... 
      return body(...)
   ```

Obviously, the output is incorrect, but at least the gradients are computed.

Comment: what if you use `tf.gradients( g, x )[0]` instead of `tf.gradients(fx,[x])[0]` when evaluate the gradient, is the error still there? `x` is a tensor or a list of tensors? Sorry there is no simple code example that can reproduce your question.

Comment: Interesting suggestion, but it didn't help. I updated the question with the full stack trace. I have never seen this error, and really can't find anybody else mentioning it.

Comment: My guess is that I found a bug in the gradients implementation. I will probably post something on the tensorflow bug tracker

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar issue. Some patterns I noted:

- If the `x` used in `tf.gradients` was used in a manner that required dimension broadcasting in `body`, I got this error. If I changed it to one that didn't require broadcasting, `tf.gradients` returned `[None]`. I didn't test this extensively, so this pattern may not be consistent across all examples.
- Both cases (returning `[None]` and raising this assertion error)  can be resolved by differentiating `tf.identity(y)` rather than just `y`: `grads = tf.gradients(tf.identity(y), xs)` I have absolutely no idea why this works.